# Jmeter How to avoid calling the same HTTP Req. for different conditions

Tags: jmeter

I have a test case scenario, where I need to test for several conditions.  say for example I have the following defaultJson for 3 sets of test cconditions (A1, A2, A3):

```
{
  "name": "Dummy",
  "condition": "A1"
}
```

1) Create and account : HTTP Req with --> "condition": "A1"

2-10) 8 different HTTP Requests are executed

11)  Create and account : HTTP Req with --> "condition": "A2"

steps 2 -10 exactly are repeated

12) Create and account : HTTP Req with --> "condition": "A3"

steps 2 -10 exactly are repeated

I dont want to repeat the same exact steps 2-10 for each condition .

How do I tell Jmeter to do steps 2-10 for each condition.

Note each condition A1, A2, A3 should be done serially

Comment: Thank you for your comment and help. I went ahead and used FOREACH and it worked perfectly. thanks agin

Answer (score 0):

You can write steps 1-10 in a loop with 3 counts, and add [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) which will read from a file with 3 lines, one for each condition, and set in variable as condition

```
A1
A2
A3
```

In your HTTP request use the variable value:

```
{
  "name": "Dummy",
  "condition": "${condition}"
}
```

Another option is to use [ForEach controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) while setting variables as

```
preCondition_1 = A1
preCondition_2 = A2
preCondition_3 = A3
```

And set Input `variable prefix` = `preCondition` and `Output variable` as `condition`

Comment: Thank you "user7294900" I will try this. I thought about it right after posting it.  The only thing is that steps 2-10 itself has a loop within it I hope it all works.

Comment: @user3556956 another option is to create 3 variables condition_1, condition_2 and condition_3 and loop it using http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Module Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller), you can refer either existing block of your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) or (better) [Test Fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment). This way you will be able to call your "8-10 requests" using single Module Controller without having to copy and paste them for each condition.

Check out [Using JMeter Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) guide to learn how you can avoid code duplication and re-use existing code blocks.

Comment: Thank you right after posting this I thought of using csv file and iterate through it,  will that work? I will try both your method , Module controller with "For each" and CSV